# how to insert data to existing collection in mongodb with mongodb-spark connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, collections, connector

I'm using the mongo-spark connector to connect between spark and MongoDB.
and I could not insert data to MongoDB because of spark default save mode is to error if the "table" (collection) exists
and the I try this.

```
MongoSpark.write(centenarians).option("collection", "hundredClub")*.option("mode","append")*.save();
```

but this is not an effect.
how can I solve this problem
please help me thanks!

This is error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: MongoCollection already exists
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by myself...
I share this solution (I'm using spark language by Scala):

```
centenarians
  .write
  .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
  .option("collection", "hundredClub")
  .mode("append")
  .save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm usign mongo-spark-connector_2.11.
If you have your spark data in form of Dataset or dataframe , you can save it using different modes of save method :

For example , (Java Code)

```
MongoSpark.write(yourDataSet).mode("append").option("replaceDocument","false").save();
```

It will append new data in your existing document matching it with _id on mongo collection.